# Can I fake laravel eager loading using a join?

Tags: laravel, join, eager-loading

I have read several posts on why eager loading uses multiple queries rather than joining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920540/why-cant-laravel-eloquent-use-join-for-eager-loading), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780715/how-to-use-eager-loading-and-join-in-eloquent-at-a-same-time-in-laravel-4), and [here](http://laravel.io/forum/04-04-2014-why-two-queries-in-relationships-not-join). However, I have a situation that I think warrants using a join instead of eager loading. How would I construct the query so that I can access the sub-object as if it were a normally eager loaded object?

Example: Getting people that live on a certain street, and loading that address at the same time. I don't want to load all the person's addresses, incase he lives at many places; just the places that match the query. With eager loading and whereHas I have to duplicate the query, and it's not always this simple of a query:

```
People::with(['address', function($query) use ($street_name){
  return $query->where('street_name', $street_name);
}])->whereHas('address', function($query) use ($street_name){
  return $query->where('street_name', $street_name);
})->get();
```

could be

```
People::query()->join('address', function($join){
  $join->on(...)
})->where('street_name', $street_name);
```

The problem then is that I cannot use this:

```
$person->address
```

Is there a way to take the join and massage it (using selects?) so that it appears like it was eager loaded?

Comment: These 2 queries will return different results. You want to use eloquent relationships here if a person can have more than 1 address or join if person can have 1 address only (that match this query). [Here](http://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2014-withwherehas#reply-16483) is a decent (ish) workaround for your problem with relationships.

Comment: If you do a join you can't do `$person->address->address_attribute` but you can do directly `$person->address_attribute`. Joined table's attributes will be attached to the `$person`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
People::join('addresses', 'addresses.people_id', '=', 'people.id')
->selectRaw('people.*')
->where('street_name', $street_name)
->with('addresses')
->get();
```

This uses a join and eager loading.

With the join alone, you can access the following though:

```
$person->street_address
```

Comment: Ideally I would have it go into an object so I can still access it like this: $person->address->street_address, but I suppose I could write some sort of attribute getter to see if the address is loaded or not.